# 4 column binding table into nested Map

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, jpa, nested

I have 4 entities: workflowEntity, PhaseEntity, RoundEntity and BlockEntity.
The structure is supposed to be following:

```
 Workflow:
   Phase:
     Round(optional):
       Block

or if there are no rounds, since round_id in workflow_binding table is nullable;

Workflow:
  Phase:
    Block
```

I need workflowEntity, when bound with Phase, Block or Round entities, to hold the information of those entitites, but those other entites should not contain any information of their "structural children". e.g I request getAllPhases(), then those Phases that get returned, should not contain information of any Blocks nor Rounds, because unless phases are bound within workflow, they are not tied with Blocks nor Rounds in any way. They can only be tied with Blocks and Rounds in bound workflowEntity.

I have tried to use @JoinTable (commented out examples in workflowEntity, PhaseEntity and RoundEntity), but this returned too much data, that wasnt bound to requested workflow.

Basically I need WorkflowEntity to contain fields such as:

```
    private Map<PhaseEntity, Map<RoundEntity, Set<BlockEntity>>> phaseRoundEntityMap;
    private Map<PhaseEntity, Set<BlockEntity>> phaseBlockEntityMap;
```

[image: database structure]

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="workflow")
public class WorkflowEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name= "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="days")
    private Integer days;

    /* 
   @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "workflow_binding",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_phase_id")})
    private Set<PhaseEntity> phases;*/

    //I need to map these somehow
    private Map<PhaseEntity, Map<RoundEntity, Set<BlockEntity>>> phaseRoundEntityMap;

    private Map<PhaseEntity, Set<BlockEntity>> phaseBlockEntityMap;


}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="workflow_phase")
@NoDuplicatePhases
public class PhaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 1500)
    private String description;

    private Integer sequenceNumber;

   // Phase shouldnt actually contain any information about blocks nor rounds, unless bound with a workflow. 

    /* Commented out, because includes blocks and rounds not bound to requested workflow
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE},  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "workflow_binding",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_phase_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_block_id")})
    private Set<BlockEntity> blocks;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "workflow_binding",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_phase_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_round_id")})
    private Set<RoundEntity> rounds;*/
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="workflow_round")
@NoDuplicateRounds
public class RoundEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    private String name;

    private Integer sequenceNumber;

    /*Commented out, because includes blocks not bound to requested workflow
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "workflow_binding",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_round_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_block_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private Set<BlockEntity> blocks;*/
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "workflow_block")
public class BlockEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 1500)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "workflow_assignment_block",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_block_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_assignment_id")})
    private Set<AssignmentEntity> assignments;

    private Integer sequenceNumber;

    @Column(name = "due_date_day")
    private Integer dueDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create an entity `WorkflowBinding`?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workflow_binding")
public class WorkflowBinding {

    @EmbeddedId
    private WorkflowBindingId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "block_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private BlockEntity block;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "round_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private RoundEntity round;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "phase_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private PhaseEntity phase;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private WorkflowEntity workflow;
}

@Embeddable
public class WorkflowBindingId {
    private UUID blockId;
    private UUID roundId;
    private UUID phaseId;
    private UUID workflowId;
}
```

On the inverse side you can then do mappings like this:

```
public class BlockEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "block")
    private Set<WorkflowBinding> bindings;

    ....
}
```